# assignment for sorting lists

Tags: java, collections

My chapter 16 assignment is this.

> Create an application which
>
> - accepts user input of a string or words
> - prints each word back in alphabetical order
> - prints the total number of elements typed

I have this so far

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Chapter16Assignment {
        public static void main(String[] args){

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


            String userInput = "";
            System.out.print(" Enter a line of words: ");
            userInput = input.nextLine();
            List<String> userString = Arrays.asList(userInput);
            String[]userInput
            //userString.add(userInput);
            //.split
            Collections.sort(userString);
            System.out.println(userString);
            //System.out.println("Frequency of words: " + Collection.frequency(userString));

            }



    }
```

I need to use split or something. i thought i could use sort method and frequency for part 3.

I expect the output to be enter a line of words then for it to print those words in alphabetical order, then the amount of words. at the moment its not doing any of that. its getting the users input though.

Comment: Yes you can use split. `split("")`

Comment: how? ive been trying so much . I know i need String[] or something sigh. i cant get it to work

Comment: `String[] userInputSplit = userInput.split("")` Though You might wanna remove all white spaces before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can use split method to convert string to string array. 
I am not using list since I want to show you a slightly different approach to do this problem.

I am removing white spaces and converting everything to lower case. It is up to you if you want to do it.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput;
System.out.print("Enter a line of words: ");
userInput = input.nextLine().replace(" ", "").toLowerCase();
String[] userInputSplit = userInput.split(""); // Splits array
Arrays.sort(userInputSplit); // Sorts array
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(userInputSplit)); // Prints sorted array
// Checks for frequency of each letter using maps
Map<String, Integer> countMap = Arrays.stream(userInputSplit)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v -> 1, Integer::sum));
// Prints map
System.out.println("Frequency of words: " + countMap.toString());
```

**Output:**

```
Enter a line of words: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
[a, b, c, d, e, e, e, f, g, h, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, o, o, o, p, q, r, r, s, t, t, u, u, v, w, x, y, z]
Frequency of words: {a=1, b=1, c=1, d=1, e=3, f=1, g=1, h=2, i=1, j=1, k=1, l=1, m=1, n=1, o=4, p=1, q=1, r=2, s=1, t=2, u=2, v=1, w=1, x=1, y=1, z=1}
```

---

Edit:

Like @AndyTurner Suggested You can use `Collectors.counting()` as well which makes the syntax a bit easier to understand but it will return Long instead of Integer

```
Map<String, Long> countMap = Arrays.stream(userInputSplit)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Collectors.counting is essentially

```
Map<String, Integer> countMap = Arrays.stream(userInputSplit)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v -> 1L, Long::sum));
```

**Using HashSet and Collections.frequency:**

```
HashSet<String> uniqueValues = new HashSet<String>(userInputList);
for (String value : uniqueValues) {
    System.out.println("Frequency of " + value + " is: " + Collections.frequency(userInputList, value));
}
```

Comment: `Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a, Collectors.counting())` might be a neater way to collect (nb it returns `Long` rather than `Integer` counts).

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ph7ku7        we didnt lean this so i was afraid to get points off. is there no way to use frequency and map and foreach to check each item in this lists after a split

Comment: @tmanrocks999 Does this work? By the way it is `split("")` there is no space between quotes.

Comment: i just found the hashset thing in my notes thanks. yes this works.

Comment: if i do no space it counts the characters, least what i have. i think he wants counts for wordshttp://prntscr.com/ph7zgk

Comment: @tmanrocks999 Oh ok. Nvm. Can you please accept the answer by selecting tick mark next to it. Thanks